# My code to capture a video from the default camera works fine on every device except the Galaxy S2 when specifying MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT path

Tags: android, video-capture

I have code that gives me back a path to store my video file which basically produces a path that looks like this:

```
/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/MyApp/MyApp20130816_144111_1131938614.mp4
```

When I try to capture the video on my S2, I take the video and press stop the camera my camera app does not display the normal save screen, it just puts itself back into the beginning of capture mode and onActivityResult is never called. I've found that if I do not pass a path to MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT it functions correctly. 
I've tested my code on Note II, GS3, GS4, Nexus and they all seem to be able to capture the video and save it to the correct path with no problems. Why would the S2 be behaving this way?

Comment: Third-party camera apps, whether they come from a device manufacturer or a third party, will not necessarily honor all requests the same way from your app. While they all *should* have the documented behavior, there is nothing *forcing* them to have the documented behavior.

Comment: I am using the default camera app as installed on the galaxy devices. I've actually found if I set the EXTRA_OUTPUT to /sdcard/temp it works as expected. Something about the galaxy s2 doesn't like /storage/ maybe?

Answer (score 0):

> Something about the galaxy s2 doesn't like /storage/ maybe?

Never hardcode paths. **Always** use methods like `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` to get the root of where to store files on external storage. Different devices, and even different users on the same device (Android 4.2+ tablets) will have different paths for external storage.

However, the point in my initial comment still holds. You as a developer are *not* "using the default camera app as installed on the galaxy devices". You as a *user* may be using that particular app. There are nearly a *billion* Android device users; you are not all of them. They are welcome to use whatever camera app they want to, including third-party ones. And, they will be using thousands of Android device models. None of them will necessarily honor your request to take a picture. It's certainly worthwhile for you to do testing to try to work more faithfully on more devices (such as not hardcoding paths), but you need to bear in mind that any time you ask another developer's app to do work for you, the other developer is control of what happens, much more than you are.

Comment: I am using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES). I understand what you are saying but in this case the camera app I am using as a user appears to support the functionality of taking a picture/video and saving it in order for my app to use. In this particular case the S2 appears to have some sort of bug or internal crash that is not allowing me to save to the above path like other devices. What is the correct way of handling this type of functionality then?

Comment: @Mr_E: "I am using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)" -- that should always return something that apps will recognize. So I have no idea why the S2 camera app would be unhappy with it. Though you might try `DIRECTORY_DCIM` instead of `DIRECTORY_PICTURES`. "What is the correct way of handling this type of functionality then?" -- either ensure the users are aware of the possible limitations of camera apps, or take the picture/video yourself.